# LIRC With Multiple IR Emitters

Tags: lirc

How do I get multiple instances of LIRC working and each using different GPIO?

Right now I do:

```
sudo lircd --device=/dev/lirc0 --pidfile=/var/run/lirc/lirc0.pid --listen=8700 --connect=localhost:8700 --output=/var/run/lirc/lircd
```

And when I do:

```
echo "SEND_ONCE TIME_WARNER KEY_0" | nc localhost 8700
```

It works.

But if I do:

```
sudo lircd --device=/dev/lirc1 --pidfile=/var/run/lirc/lirc1.pid --listen=8701 --connect=localhost:8701 --output=/var/run/lirc/lircd
```

And : `echo "SEND_ONCE TIME_WARNER KEY_0" | nc localhost 8701`

It doesn't work. 
How do I set the proper GPIO on `/dev/lirc1`?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repository containing *lirc*? Your answer is probably there.

Comment: We are going to need to see this `lirc` repository and the error you receive after you run your echo command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Multiple_LIRC_Drivers) goes about it by creating a new instance of the driver.
In short:

```
$ find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name lirc_serial.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.31-21-generic/kernel/ubuntu/lirc/lirc_serial/lirc_serial.ko
$ cd /lib/modules/2.6.31-21-generic/kernel/ubuntu/lirc/lirc_serial
$ su
# cat lirc_serial.ko | sed -e 's/lirc_serial/lirc_ser_01/g' > lirc_ser_01.ko
# depmod -a
# exit
$
$ sudo modprobe lirc_ser_01
$ dmesg | tail
lirc_ser_01: auto-detected active high receiver
lirc_dev: lirc_register_driver: sample_rate: 0
lirc_ser_01 $Revision: 5.104 $ registered
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running two instances on my pi I opted to make what is essentially a transistor switchboard (on a breadboard). I call each send command from a script which first runs another script that turns on one of three GPIOs, activating one of three transistors, and thus exposing one of three IR transmitters to receive signal from the single LIRC gpio.

This actually works very well, and I was able to put this together in less time than it takes to read the tutorials on multiple instances and drivers. I needed this ability because I have multiple components which are of the same make and therefore receive some of the same codes such as power. If each device didn't have it's own transmitter I wouldn't be able to control one device without the other non intended device also responding to the command.

Comment: This hardware fix is great because it’ll avoid a potential software update that could break the multiple GPIO pins fix with LIRC. You know LIRC will always support at least one pin and the hardware solution will always support multiple pins. Thanks for this idea. I’m working on this project now and will use this solution.